# How to apply a "without" filter in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have and array of with `allEntries` and an array with `alreadyUpdatedEntries`. I would like to filter out all the `alreadyUpdatedToEntries` to end up with an array of `notUpdatedEntries`. Like how it is done in Twig.

```
{% set notUpdatedEntries = allEntries|without(alreadyUpdatedEntries) %}
```

Is there a similar Craft PHP method to do this in my plugin? Can I maybe include this in my elements criteria query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use similar logic that Craft uses for the [withoutFilter](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension#withoutFilter-detail) in [CraftTwigExtension](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension).

```
public function withoutFilter($arr, $exclude)
{
    $filteredArray = array();

    if (!is_array($exclude))
    {
        $exclude = array($exclude);
    }

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, $exclude))
        {
            $filteredArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $filteredArray;
}
```

Comment: @RitterKnight That's what I get for posting before coffee.

Comment: Been there, done that!